# Why doesn't the function use the default value?

Tags: python, function, recursion, arguments

I tried to write a string matching program using a recursive function. The function first creates an empty list called tuple1 to add the points. Then it returns the list. However, when I try to use this function twice, the function adds the points to the list created in the previous function. Why doesn't the function use the default value tuple1 = [] in the second call? Any ideas??

The output of the program:

[0, 3, 5, 9, 11, 12, 15, 19]

[0, 3, 5, 9, 11, 12, 15, 19, 0, 5, 15]

btw this is an assignment from OpenCourseWare shared by MIT.

```
def subStringMatchExact(target, key, counter=0, tuple1=[]):
    if len(target) < len(key):
       return tuple1

    else:
       counter += 1

       if target[:len(key)] == key:
          tuple1.append(counter-1)
       return subStringMatchExact(target[1:], key, counter, tuple1)

print(subStringMatchExact("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat", "a"))
print(subStringMatchExact("atgacatgcacaagtatgcat", "atg"))
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/494134

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you for the comment. That's exactly my problem.

Comment: Default parameters in functions are bound to the function declaration, so you get a default variable as an instance, not a fresh copy every time you call the function, it's a classic gotcha in python. To get what you want to do: you define the list in the body of the function.

Comment: @garglblarg if I do that won't the function return an empty list since it is recursive?

Comment: Hint: Don't name your variable `tuple1` when it is in fact a `list`, especially one that is mutated.

Comment: A key point to remember here is that default args are *always* evaluated when the function object is originally created, not when it's called.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is:

```
def foo(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = []
    # do stuff
```

You can read more here http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 2):

Because the default value is a reference to the default value, it's not created every time.
Hence if you run a sample like that:

```
def f(x=[]):
    x.append(1)
    return x
print(f()) #prints [1]
print(f()) #prints [1,1]
```

A workaround can be using a tuple which is immutable and converting it to a list:

```
def f(x=()):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        input = list(x)
    else:
        input = x
    input.append(1)
    return input
print(f()) #[1]
print(f()) #[1]
```

With that way it will work

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I guess it is because "everything is an object" concept. Am I right?

Comment: I guess that the reason is that the default value is stored "compile time", and then a reference is generated. Every time you call the function the default value is loaded from that memory address, so if it's modified the modified version of it will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a mutable object as a default value, here comes the confusion. Here, tuple1 just adds to the list every time you call your function. The following is a work around:

```
def subStringMatchExact(target, key, counter=0, tuple1=None):
    if tuple1 == None:
        tuple1 = []
    if len(target) < len(key):
       return tuple1

    else:
       counter += 1

       if target[:len(key)] == key:
          tuple1.append(counter-1)
       return subStringMatchExact(target[1:], key, counter, tuple1)
```

Comment: It works perfectly.

Comment: @sorccery great to know that. Thank you.